# What's the point of bringing passport photos to one's naturalization interview?

Tags: usa, citizenship

I [read](https://www.jqklaw.com/what-documents-do-i-need-to-bring-to-my-naturalization---citizenship-interview-.html):

> Although not required (unless residing outside of the US), it is recommended that you bring two additional passport-style photos (2”x2”). The photos must be in color with face, frontal view, on a white to off-white background. Head height measure 1” to 1 3/8” from top of hair to bottom of the chin, and eye height between 1 1/8” to 1 3/8” from the bottom of the photo. For additional specifications, please visit [this page](https://www.jqklaw.com/photo-standards-and-requirements-for-us-immigration--visas-and-consulates.html).

What's the point of bringing passport photos to one's naturalization interview? Assume one resides in the United States as a single individual.

Comment: One went on my wife's naturalization certificate.  As that was 30 years ago things might have changed so I'm only making this a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: @LorenPechtel thanks, do you recall where the second went?

Comment: No idea, I don't even remember how many photos she brought.

Answer (score 1):

So that you could submit your passport application right there. Many times, especially at large ceremonies, the passport office will send their people to collect passport applications right after the ceremony. Otherwise you'll need to set up a special appointment which may take significantly longer. Bring a checkbook as well (to pay for the passport).